# Writing PSD files with python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, photoshop, psd

I have a PSD file with 3 layers. What I want to do is change the 3rd, deepest layer's image and save the whole PSD file as PNG.

Is this possible with python or the ubuntu command line?

I've already looked at [psd tools](https://github.com/kmike/psd-tools) but it's only good for exporting images as PNG in my case, I've looked at this [blog post](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html) but not sure if it will allow me to change layer's image and where to find some documentation

Comment: Photoshop can be scripted natively using JavaScript. If you go this route you will find better documentation, support and a better coding experience. Is there any particular reason you want to use Python for this?

Comment: @kartikg3 this code will be used in Django project so using python would be a huge advantage.

Comment: Oh yes for sure. And this is on a windows machine right?

Comment: You have python's win32com library setup?

Comment: @kartikg3 Isn't that windows library ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69072/discussion-between-marijus-and-kartikg3).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need Python, try to use [photoshop-python-api](https://pypi.org/project/photoshop-python-api/)

But even this not support all the functionalities of Photoshop.

Win32com API can give a vast range of functionalities but it's for windows.

Have you ever tried ExtendScript JS for Phothoshop? This is a built-in script editor for Adobe and a script listener is also available so you can easily make functions you need.

- [Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/Photoshop-CS6-JavaScript-Ref.pdf)
- [Scripting Listener](https://helpx.adobe.com/mena_en/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html)